# android image effects

Tags: android, image, effects

i was wandering where can i find image effects libraries or templets for android

or how can i make the same effects that are in this video and can it be done with flash then changed to apk....??

at 00:13 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxLAMXR1mGM

at 00:40 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlbbIW_e8rw&feature=related

thank you

Comment: also this link i could not add it coz i don't have enough points at 00:27 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_tXWavqw_yE&feature=related

Comment: For image effects see my answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662123/photo-editing-on-phonegap-android